# Understanding a few concepts in content provider

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I am unable to understand certain concepts in the following code:

1) Why we are using.arg0.getPathSegments().get(1)?

2) What is the value of get(1)?

3) What is the functionality of 
(!TextUtils.isEmpty(arg1) ? " AND (" +  arg1 + ')' : ""), arg2);

```
public int delete(Uri arg0, String arg1, String[] arg2) {
  int count=0;
  switch (uriMatcher.match(arg0)){
     case BOOKS:
        count = booksDB.delete(
           DATABASE_TABLE,
           arg1, 
           arg2);
        break;
     case BOOK_ID:
        String id = arg0.getPathSegments().get(1);
        count = booksDB.delete(
           DATABASE_TABLE,                        
           _ID + " = " + id + 
           (!TextUtils.isEmpty(arg1) ? " AND (" + 
           arg1 + ')' : ""), 
           arg2);
        break;
     default: throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Unknown URI " + arg0);    
  }       
  getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(arg0, null);
  return count;
```

Comment: 1/ read the doc. that's the 2nd path segment. look at the uri format, that should make sense. 2/ debug it or log it, that depends on the arg0 Uri 3/ that's a ternary notation. it is used to add a condition on arg1 is arg1 exists.

Answer (score 0):

1) Why we are using.arg0.getPathSegments().get(1)?

> Suppose you queried with uri content://[Authority]/foo/bar
>   getPathsegments will return you a list with foo and bar ( not
>   authority)

2) What is the value of get(1)?

> So for above case get(1) will give you second item on the list i.e
>   bar

3) What is the functionality of (!TextUtils.isEmpty(arg1) ? " AND (" + arg1 + ')' : ""), arg2);

> the delete function signature is

```
   public int delete(Uri url, String where, String[] whereArgs)
```

> So if `where` string is not null the condition is being appended to
>   the db delete operation.